# C++ blogs that you regularly follow?

Tags: c++, blogs

What are all the C++ blogs that you follow?

***Please add one url for one posting.***

Answer (score 94):

[Sutter's Mill](http://herbsutter.wordpress.com/)

Answer (score 70):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++ ;-)

Comment: Are you suggesting that SO is a blog? :-)

Comment: If the C++ info on SO isn't a "Blog" then I consider it a "blog".

Answer (score 44):

[Visual C++ Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/)

Stephan T. Lavavej's (STL's!) posts in particular.

Comment: ++ Stephan is always incredibly insightful.

Comment: I have learned so much from his Channel 9 videos. +1

Answer (score 32):

[C++ Soup!](http://www.cplusplus-soup.com/) C++ Tips, Tricks, Reviews, and Commentary By Dean Michael Berris.

Comment: new site http://www.cplusplus-soup.com/

Answer (score 27):

[C++ Truths](http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 24):

[DrDobb's C++ Blog](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp)

Comment: Please add one url per post and vote if some one had already added

Answer (score 21):

[The Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/)

Comment: Seems to deal most with Front End programming in GDI (MFC??)

Comment: The Old New Thing deals with a lot of Win32 API topics, as well as a lot of interesting windows history. It doesn't cover MFC. For a general overview of the blog, see  http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/APIWar.html

Answer (score 19):

[C++Next](http://cpp-next.com/)

Answer (score 16):

[Power of 2 Games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cybersquatting)

Update: The articles are now hosted at [Games From Within](http://gamesfromwithin.com/?paged=7).

Comment: but the linked content seems to be spammy.

Comment: I've mailed Noel to see what's up and where the content has gone.

Comment: I think he's moved on to iPhone development so he's more interested in Objective-C

Answer (score 16):

[The C++ Source](http://www.artima.com/cppsource)

Answer (score 15):

[The View from Aristeia](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/) formerly [Scott Meyers Mailing List](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/scott_meyers/)

Answer (score 14):

[C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/)

Comment: If you read C++ FAQ lite, don't forget to take a look at C++ FQA (http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/), it helps you take C++FAQ lite with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 12):

[Thinking Asynchronously in C++](http://think-async.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 11):

[Bartosz Milewski’s Programming Cafe: Concurrency, Multicore, Language Design, D, C++](http://bartoszmilewski.wordpress.com/)

Answer (score 10):

Not a blog but new C++ contents are added frequently: [More C++ Idioms](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms)

Answer (score 9):

[Google Testing Blog](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/) covers all kinds of great testing tips and techniques.

Answer (score 8):

[Andrew Koenig's Blog](http://dobbscodetalk.com/index.php?option=com_myblog&blogger=andrewk&Itemid=29)

Answer (score 8):

[Reddit C++](http://www.reddit.com/r/cpp)

Answer (score 5):

[mr-edd.co.uk](http://www.mr-edd.co.uk/)

Answer (score 5):

[Rambling Comments](http://www.lenholgate.com/index.rdf) ([Len Holgate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7925/len-holgate)'s blog)

Answer (score 5):

I used to follow the [GotW](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/).

Answer (score 4):

[Attractive Chaos](http://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/)

Answer (score 4):

[C/C++ About.com](http://cplus.about.com)

Answer (score 4):

[Garry's Bit Patterns](http://blog.programmerslog.com/) (though it's mainly about Python these days).

Answer (score 4):

[Just Software Solutions](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/blog/)

Answer (score 4):

[LightSleeper](http://pkisensee.spaces.live.com/)

Answer (score 4):

[The Fastware Project](http://fastwareproject.blogspot.com/) by Scott Meyers

Answer (score 4):

ACCU (Association of C and C++ Users) journal:

http://accu.org/index.php/journals/c78/

Answer (score 3):

[Learning c++](http://learningcppisfun.blogspot.com/) by Abhishek Padmanabh

Answer (score 2):

[Learn C++](http://www.learncpp.com/posts/)

Answer (score 2):

[Intel Software Blogs](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/) (not purely C++, but a lot of postings are)

Answer (score 2):

[Just Software Solutions / C++](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/cplusplus/) (C++ by Anthony Williams)

Answer (score 2):

[STLab Papers and Presentations](http://stlab.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Papers_and_Presentations)

Answer (score 2):

[The C++ Standards Committee WG papers](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/)

Answer (score 2):

Danny Kalev's [blog and articles](http://www.informit.com/authors/bio.aspx?a=e19aded6-574c-4c46-8511-101f9f0ed8f8) and the updates on his c++ reference [guide](http://www.informit.com/guides/guide.aspx?g=cplusplus) both on informIT

Answer (score 1):

[Poco](http://pocoproject.org/blog)

Answer (score 1):

[DevX: C++ Zone](http://www.devx.com/cplus/Door/7042)

Answer (score 1):

[KenanLee](http://kenanlee.blogspot.com/search/label/C%2FC%2B%2B)

Answer (score 1):

[C++ Next](http://cpp-next.com/)

Answer (score 1):

[Bannalia: trivial notes on themes diverse](http://bannalia.blogspot.com/) from Joaquín M López Muñoz, the author of Boost.Multiindex, includes some interesting C++ articles.

Answer (score 1):

[Visual C++ Weekly news](http://paper.li/visualc/news/)

Answer (score 1):

[Andrzej's C++ blog](http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codemaestro.com/

Answer (score 0):

http://embracingcpp.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0):

http://cplusplus.co.il

Answer (score 0):

[Modern C++](http://pizer.wordpress.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[Google C++ Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml)

Answer (score 0):

[C / C++ Programming Recipes For The Impatient Programmer](http://thecprogrammer.com)

Answer (score 0):

[MasterCplusplus (For Beginners)](http://mastercplusplus.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[CodeProject.](http://www.codeproject.com)

Answer (score 0):

[Mad Software](http://madsoftware.blogspot.com/)