# What are the best RSS feeds for C++?

Tags: c++, rss, g++, feed

What are the best RSS feeds for C++ ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/c%2b%2b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151974/c-blogs-that-you-regularly-follow) lists C++ blogs, most of those blogs have rss feeds.

Also...don't forget the rss feed for the Stackoverflow C++ tag!