# C++ Report alternatives?

Tags: c++

I came across this recommendation for reading the C++ report magazine. However, when I searched for it, i realized it has become defunct.

Can someone please recommend me some other magazine / rss etc which is of the same genre ? I look forward to read more about some of the elusive and other C++ techniques that veterans are using in the field.

I came across Dr. Dobb's journal -> C++ feeds and I think they're pretty good too. Subscribed++

Thanks!

Comment: You might check out this list of C++ blogs:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151974/c-blogs-that-you-regularly-follow

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The obvious choices would be [C Vu](http://accu.org/index.php/aboutus/aboutjournals) and [Overload](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/c78/), both published by the [ACCU](http://accu.org) (formerly known as the *Association of C and C++ Users*).

Also, even though this isn't a magazine, a great source of C++related material that is updated quite often is Herb Sutter's blog: [Sutter's Mill](http://herbsutter.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Uncle Bob Martin's [Object Mentor](http://objectmentor.com/) publications include all his classics from C++ Report.

Comment: I'd be *very* wary of these, as they pretty much all predate the C++ standardization. This in itself isn't a huge problem, but it means they also predate modern C++ practices (which means it's more about C with Classes than about what we would consider C++ today)

Comment: Not really.  If you read them, you'll see that the concepts are usually generic OO, not outdated C++ syntax.

Comment: C++ Report is no longer, and became C Users Journal before becoming Dr. Dobbs Journal Source: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CppReport

Comment: Yes, I know.  C++ Report died long ago.  That's why I referred to Object Mentor.  Citing C++ Report was only for historical context and interest, nothing more.